# Help me with this integral

Tags: integration, logarithms

Find the value of $$\int\frac{1+\ln x}{4+x\ln x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$ I have a very bad understanding of integrals where some function of a variable is in the denominator. I know I have to do some kind of substitution and I even tried that but can't get any help from it. Please forgive me if this is a very simple question because I am really bad at integrals (denominator ones).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $(lnx)^2$ or $ln(x^2)$?

Comment: Is it $(\ln x)^2$ or $\ln(x^2)=2\ln x$?

Comment: most probably $ln(x^2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x\ln(x^2)=2\cdot x\ln x. $$
Now, try to differentiate the function $f(x)= x\ln x.$ So by using the product rule, $$\frac{d}{dx}(x\ln x)= x\cdot\frac 1x + 1\cdot \ln x=1+\ln x.$$ This is the numerator of your integrand. Hence, substitute $x\ln x=u$, (you could also do $4+2x \ln x=u$) so that $du=(1+\ln x)dx$. Hence the integral becomes $$\int \frac{du}{4+2u}$$ Now put $4+2u=t$ so that $2du=dt$. Thus we get $$ \int \frac{du}{4+2u}=\int \frac{dt}{2t}=\frac 12 \ln t+C= \frac 12 \ln(2u+4)+c= \frac 12 \ln(2x\ln x+4)+C= \frac 12 \ln(x\ln(x^2)+4)+C.$$ where $C$ is the integration constant.

Comment: Hi. Use `\ln`. Generally common notations are prefaced with a backslash in MathJax

Answer (score 0):

First note that $\ln(x^2)$ is just $2\ln x$. Then, consider a funciton $f(x) = ln(a+bx\ln(x))$ then you have:

$$f'(x) = \frac{b+b\ln(x)}{a+bx\ln x}$$

Now, you are in the path to find your answer.